# Find set with derived set $A=\{1/n\,:\,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have some doubts about an exercise..

My teacher proposed find the set $B$ such that its derived set $B´=A$ where $A=\{\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{Z^+}\}$..

But the derived set must be closed in $\mathbb{R}$, (
I remembered this now).

---

I proposed this set 
$$B=\{\frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{n}} . k,n \in \mathbb Z^+, k*n\neq 1 \}$$
but if fixed $n=1$ then, $$lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{k-1}}=0$$

then $0 $ is accumulation point of $B$. Is it correct??

---

$0$ must also be a limit point of B?? why?

Perhaps the $0$ should always be a point of accumulation of any set ?

---

and this set, $$B=\cup_{m\in \mathbb{N}}\{\frac{n+1}{mn},n\in N\}$$

fixed $n=1$, $0$ is accumularion point for $B$.

---

-How would you prove that there are no more accumulation points in that set?

Comment: As $B'$ must be closed, $A\subseteq B'$ implies $\overline A\subseteq B$. And $0\in \overline A$.

Comment: Not possible if A subset R.  Thus take A subset R - {0}.

Comment: Hagan Von Eitzen. why $A \subseteq B^{\prime}$ implies $\bar{A} \subseteq B $?

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that $0 \in A'$. Any neighbourhood of $0$ contains all but finitely many of the $\frac{1}{n}$. If $x \neq 0$ there is always a neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $A \cap U_x = \{x\}$ (if $x \in A$) or $U_x \cap A = \emptyset$.
This holds as any $x > 0 $ has possibly two $x^-, x^+ \in A$ with $x^- < x < x^+$ such that $(x^-,x) \cap A = \emptyset$ and $(x,x^+) \cap A =\emptyset$ (the left and right neighbours of $x$) and then $(x^-, x^+)= U_x$ is as required. In other words, the set $A$ has the discrete topology as a subspace. But it has one limit point outside of $A$, namely $0$, so $A' = \{0\}$ (indeed a closed set, as it should be).

Comment: I think you are answering a different question, namely, determining what $A'$ is, rather than finding $B $ such that $A=B'$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I think you're correct. I read too fast.